# Permission denied (publickey) on github

Tags: git, github

I work to understand Ruby on Rails with a tutorial of M Hartl.
I have finished chapter 6 and `git push` the work on git-hub, but I received this error:

> rene@Linux-Ubuntu:~/rails_projets/sample_app$ git push Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I reinstalled a new publickey as a Help-Git instruction

```
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Offering DSA public key: rene@Linux-Ubuntu
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug1: Offering RSA public key: rene@Linux-Ubuntu
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug1: Trying private key: [~/.ssh/id_rsa]
    debug1: Trying private key: [~/.ssh/id_dsa]
    debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
    Permission denied (publickey).
```

And I have the files in a repository:

> rene@Linux-Ubuntu:~/.ssh$ ls
>   ak.bak  config  id_dsa  id_dsa.pub id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  key_backup/  known_hosts

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please post the output of git remote -v in your sample app directory.

Answer (score 2):

Have you told github about your public key?

https://github.com/settings/ssh

(it's the contents of `id_rsa.pub` that you need)